# Matlab if loop running but not giving correct output

Tags: matlab, loops

I have an if loop, which for the most part works correctly, but the first if loop part is supposed to provide my resulting matrix in zeroes as long as the loop is below a certain threshold (12,4 in my case) however, it does not do this at the moment.

I have tried to replace everything, and rewrite it. I am currently following a guide, so I do not have an extensive amount of knowledge on the subject. I have tried to manually calculate the matrix positions, which should result in zero, which it also amounted to.

```
T_A4 = 12.4
t_coA = 3
F_redA = 0.99

for i = 5:25                                                                
t_r = i;                                                                    
I(i,1) = 10980*(i*60).^(-0.71);                                         
    for n = 1:60
    t = n;                                                             
        if n < T_A4 
            Q(t,i) = 0;
        end
        if T_A4 <= t < t_coA + T_A4
            Q(t,i) = I(i,1)*F_redA*(t-T_A4)/t_coA;
        end
        if t_coA + T_A4 <= t < T_A4 + t_r
            Q(t,i) = I(i,1)*F_redA;
        end    
        if t_r + T_A4 <= t < T_A4 + t_coA + t_r
            Q(t,i) = I(i,1)*F_redA*(1-(t-T_A4-t_r)/t_coA);
        end    
        if t >= T_A4 + t_coA + t_r
            Q(t,i) = 0;
        end
    end
end
```

Expected result should be a Q matrix where Q(1:12,:) = 0, however from Q(1:12,5:25) these all results in values that is not 0.

An example is Q(1,5) should result in 0, as n=1 is < 12.4. However my resulting Q(1,5) = 1225.1 :(

Comment: `for` is a loop. `if` is just a conditional.

Comment: Yes, but the first conditional loop (if n < T_A4) should be 0, when the for loop is running from 0 to 12. Thats what i planed for at least.

Comment: What do you think the line `T_A4 = 12,4` is doing? What is the `,4` meant to define? Spoiler: the `,4` is doing nothing here... Do you mean `12.4`?

Comment: Ah, yes. It is 12.4, not 12,4. It is calculated at another point in my code, so it is correctly defined there, however i misswrote in the window here; I have now fixed the mistake.

Comment: `a < x < b` does not do what you think it does in MATLAB. Instead, write `a < x & C < b`.

Comment: A tip: run smaller bits of your code to see what they do. And use the debugger to step through your code and check the flow and the value of variables to see if they match your expectations. MATLAB has really fantastic debugging capabilities.